# Left Icon Inside Text Box

Tags: angular, xml, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript. I am trying to place a icon inside the textbox but it is not working. Please Help me out.

Expected O/P

[image: Actual O/P]

**Code**

```
            <GridLayout columns="*, *" rows="auto">
            <TextField row="0" col="0" hint="Height">
             <Image src="../../abc.png">
            </TextField>
            <TextField row="0" col="1" hint="Weight">
            <Image src="../../cde.png">
           </TextField>
           </GridLayout>
```

I am getting the textbox without icon. Please get me out

Answer (score 0):

A `TextField` doesn't accept images inside it. One way to do it is to wrap your `TextField` inside a `GridLayout` and add the icon inside the `GridLayout` instead.

The first `TextField` would be

```html
<GridLayout rows="auto" columns="auto, *">
  <Image row="0" col="0" src="../../abc.png"></Image>
  <TextField row="0" col="1" hint="Height"></TextField>
</GridLayout>
```

So both Textfields together would look like this:

```html
<GridLayout columns="*, *" rows="auto">

  <!-- first textfield -->
  <GridLayout row="0" col="0" rows="auto" columns="auto, *">
    <Image row="0" col="0" src="../../abc.png"></Image>
    <TextField row="0" col="1" hint="Height"></TextField>
  </GridLayout>

  <!-- second textfield -->
  <GridLayout row="0" col="1" rows="auto" columns="auto, *">
    <Image row="0" col="0" src="../../cde.png"></Image>
    <TextField row="0" col="1" hint="Height"></TextField>
  </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```